# Error while installing language pack via composer require in magento 2

Tags: magento2, language, composer

I am getting below while running `composer require mageplaza/magento-2-dutch-language-pack:*`

```
The requested package mageplaza/magento-2-dutch-language-pack * is satisfiable by mageplaza/magento-2-dutch-language-pack[dev-master] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

composer.json

```
{
  "name": "mageplaza/magento-2-dutch-language-pack",
  "description": "Dutch language package for Magento 2",
  "homepage": "https://www.mageplaza.com",
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0"
  },
  "type": "magento2-language",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "MIT"
  ],
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Mageplaza team",
      "email": "hi@mageplaza.com",
      "homepage": "https://www.mageplaza.com",
      "role": "Leader"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "registration.php"
    ]
  }
}
```

Can any one help me on this.

Comment: Can you post your `composer.json`?

Comment: Please see this resource link , i downloaded, updated with my question. https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-dutch-language-pack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, this package has [no releases](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-dutch-language-pack/releases). For composer that means, if you require a minimum stability of anything above **dev** in your projects composer.json, it will refuse to install this package.

Now you have two options: loosen your minimum stability, by changing the "minimum-stability" line in your composer.json to

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

Or explicitly require a dev version of the package by appending `@dev` to the version constraint, i.e.

```
"mageplaza/magento-2-dutch-language-pack": "*@dev",
```

or

```
"mageplaza/magento-2-dutch-language-pack": "dev-master@dev",
```